Filtering a draft in immer doesn't affect the base state
What I'm trying to do is filter an array using immer, but it doesn't seem to be working.
You can see a reproduction of the issue here:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/immerjs-forked-r6sqkz


const { produce } = immer;

const baseState = [
  {
    todo: "One",
    done: false,
  },
  {
    todo: "Two",
    done: false,
  },
  {
    todo: "Three",
    done: true,
  },
  {
    todo: "Four",
    done: true,
  },
  {
    todo: "Five",
    done: false,
  },
];

const filterState = produce(baseState, (draft) => {
  draft = draft.filter((record) => {
    return record.done === true;
  });

  console.log("DRAFT: ", draft); // correct
  return draft;
});

console.log("FILTER STATE: ", filterState); // not correct
<script src="https://unpkg.com/immer@6.0.3/dist/immer.umd.production.min.js"></script>



If you open the console you'll see that the draft gets filtered properly, but when the new state doesn't reflect those changes.
Does anyone know what's going on?
Edit:
It seems that if you return draft that fixes the issue. However, according to the immer docs you shouldn't HAVE to return draft.

Where exactly is this stated in the docs?

The docs contain an example with an explicit return statement: https://immerjs.github.io/immer/update-patterns#array-mutations

By doing draft = ..., you are not mutating the draft, you are assigning a new value to the draft variable scoped to your callback function. You need to actually mutate the array (using splice for example) in order for it to work without a return value. But if a filter is easier to write, you should definitely use a return statement as in the docs example pointed out by @KostasMinaidis
